# Angular reactive forms using minlength only shows error when length is 0

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

Even though i have set the minlength to 5 it only gives me an error when the length is 0.

here is a plunker i have made that demonstrates that:

https://plnkr.co/edit/bJ9zeArGykATtRGh3Zev?p=preview

This is how i set the validation:

```
  formGroup.sensitivity = 
   this.formBuilder.control(this.reportModel.sensitivity, [Validators.required, 
   Validators.minLength(5)]);
```

Comment: hehe yeah sorry :) now its there

Comment: sorry wrong plunker...

Comment: heheh now its the right one! Sorry for that :)

Comment: And you want an input of type number ?

Comment: Because if you use a text input, it works well ! https://plnkr.co/edit/94zJkOySH39CnZOekst6?p=preview

Comment: yeah it should be number input

Comment: minlength doesn't exist on number inputs

Answer (score 4):

For numbers, you should use `Validators.min()` instead of minLength() if you want to check for a number that must be minimum 5. minLength() is used for the number of characters in a text.

```
formGroup.sensitivity = 
   this.formBuilder.control(this.reportModel.sensitivity, [Validators.required, 
   Validators.min(5)]);
```